# ios 5 sdk, adding a custom control

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Can I add some custom button to cell in contacts list or in other system list?
I just want to write some utility, that will be launched from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot modify any existing apps. The only thing you can do is [register a custom URL handler](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html).